# What policy Action(s) on what Resource(s) are required to run New-EC2Tag from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-powershell

I'm attempting to run New-EC2Tag, getting the following error:

```
New-EC2Tag : You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

The user policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["ec2:DescribeInstances","ec2:CreateTags"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:<my_account_id>:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/OctopusTentacle": "yes"
            }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

It works fine in the Policy Simulator as above.

If I remove the condition and set Resource to * it works.  Removing the condition or setting Resource to * alone do not work.  I am running this as local Administrator on the instance.

What else is New-EC2Tag accessing/doing that I need to grant access to?

Answer (score 2):

If `New-EC2Tag` works when clearing the `Condition` and wildcarding the `Resource`, then we should be inspecting both of those.

From some investigation, `New-EC2Tag`'s related API action is [CreateTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CreateTags.html).  According to [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources), some API actions do not support ARNs. This seems to be the case with `CreateTags`, as it requests that you specify a resource ID instead. This is also corraborated by the "Supported Resources..." documentation I linked above, which does not list CreateTags as supporting arns.

In this case, the documentation recommends that you set the policy as such:

> If the API action does not support ARNs, use the * wildcard to specify
>   that all resources can be affected by the action.

So that leaves the condition... the tag. The tag that you are using as a condition needs to already exist on the instance for the policy to be applied as you expect.  An example from the policy simulator, where the tag already exists:

[image: DescribeTags and DescribeInstances are allowed.]

Another consideration is that the action may likewise not support conditions, but I haven't found anything to back that up.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  It works in the Simulator with arn and condition, but on further investigation neither work when calling create-tags via CLI either.  Error as follows: 'A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the CreateTags operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.'

Comment: Anthony is correct that permissions for some EC2 actions support resources and others don't. Per the EC2 docs, "[...] because you can't tag a resource when you create it, you can't use any of the tag condition keys with a resource that's created by an action. (We'll add support for tagging a resource at creation in 2014.)" (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html) 

Is this addressing your question? I hope.

Comment: Also, there's a blog post on the AWS Security Blog that walks through the process of building up a policy for EC2 access that threads its way through actions that do and don't support resource-level permissions. Dunno if that would be helpful:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2KPWZJJ4S26H6/Demystifying-EC2-Resource-Level-Permissions